# Error when import shapefile on postgis with shp2pgsql (unable to open shapefile)?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I use postgresql 9.1, postgis 2.0.1. For importing the shapefiles to my database, I use shp2pgsql. I have tried many ways for importing theses shapefiles (shp2pgsql -I roads.shp public.roads | psql -d map), but the result is always:

*Unable to open roads.shp or roads.SHP.

roads: dbf file (.dbf) can not be opened.*

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Make sure that file is around. Sometimes you can create an empty attribute file with, e.g. QGIS. However as written, this question has nothing to do with programming. Also it looks like it is a total duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74799/postgis-shapefile-loader-2-1-error-dbf-file-can-not-be-opened

Comment: Ok, finally I found the solution. For anyone who meet the same situation : you must move all your files (.shp, .shx, .dbf) up to the folder which has the directory shorter. For exemple : my old directory is '/home/myname/Desktop/' and it doesn't work, and my new directory is '/home/myname/' and it works well. It is not the problem of the files which are not around but because of the length of directory. I think this error happen only on Linux and shp2pgsql.

Comment: @JohnBarça Why would one run shp2pgsql as *postgres* user??? It is supposed to be run as a regular user and its output fed to psql that accepts `--username` etc.

Comment: @mlt, good point. The error is still most likely to do with read permissions on the files though, whatever user is being used.

Comment: @Jgan You do not use something like `sudo su postgres` before all that, do you? If you do, please do not.

Comment: It is true running as postgres user is bad practice, which I have been guilty of.

Answer (score 7):

A "shapefile" is actually more than one file (i.e., more than just a .shp file). Make sure all of the files are in the same folder when using with any GIS software, including shp2pgsql.

The minimum required files, sharing a common prefix, are:

- .shp — geometry data
- .dbf — attribute data
- .shx — geometry index file

Other files may include: .prj, .sbn, .sbx, .fbn, .fbx, .ain, .aih, .ixs, .mxs, .atx, .shp.xml, and .cpg.

Comment: Although it's theoretical answer, it was a good and well explained answer. After reading this the import worked successfully!

Answer (score 2):

After having the same problem and moving files around to smaller paths did not help, I tried with the **full** path of the .shp file instead of reffering only the filename while being in the same folder.

Fortunately this was my problem and it worked after that.

Lubuntu 12 - Postgres 9.3

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem and I found out that the path to the (.shp) and (.dbf) file contains space.

e.g. the path to your target shape file is `home/my name/shapefiles/myshape.shp` which contains a  (a space) which the terminal doesn't recognize.

The solution is to add a backslash followed by a space like `\` instead of a single space like  .

In my example, type the path in the terminal the like
`home/my\ name/shapefiles/myshape.shp` and it works just great. Try it out.

Similar to the way we handle space in string in most programing languages.

Hope it will help

Comment: And the solution raised by @allicius that uses smaller path did work in some cases because they eliminated folder name in the path that contains spaces. The rationale is suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

D:\my_files\shapefiles\ - directory name should be short , it worked for me , also in my case I replaced  '\' with '/'

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, but my case might be different from you. My shp file is located in a folder with the filename consists of symbolic character like Korean, japanese, chinese, etc. After I changed the filename to alphabet my shp file got imported successfully.